# Creating a pairwise scatterplot in R with data in a 4-way array

Tags: r, image-processing

So far I have tried a number of things in order to graph this function, however, none seem to allow me to ploy the data from the image.  The data is stored in a four-way array “im”, where the last mode of the array corresponds to a RGB color representation. I'm trying to create a pairwise scatter plot to investigate the association of the imaging pixels’ values along different color coordinates. For example, the pixel values in Red can be extracted
as “im[,,,1]”.  I have tried so far using the pairs() function and have gotten the Error: in plot.new() : figure margins too large.  I'm not necessarily sure how to appropriately graph the data in multiple scatterplots.

```
setwd("~/Downloads")
install.packages("imager")
library (imager)
library(graphics)
im <- load.image('Denny.jpg')
im 
plot(im)
img=(im[,,,1]+im[,,,2]+im[,,,3])/3
img= apply(apply(img,1,rev))
image(img,col=grey(0:12/12))
A=apply(im[,,1,1],1,rev)
image(A)

pairs(im[,,,1:3]


    setwd("~/Downloads")
    install.packages("imager")
    library (imager)
    library(graphics)
    im <- load.image('Denny.jpg')
    im
    plot(im)
    img=(im[,,,1]+im[,,,2]+im[,,,3])/3
    img= apply(apply(img,1,rev))
    image(img,col=grey(0:12/12))
    A=apply(im[,,1,1],1,rev)
    image(A)

    pairs(im[,,,1:3]
```

Comment: Try and enlarge RStudios plot pane. The message you are getting is due to RStudio using the plot pane size to define the dimensions of the plot. if the pane is too small we get the error..

Comment: I tried to look it up but how do I increase the plot plane size so that I will not get this error on a mac?

Comment: just drag the border of the windowpane

Comment: This didn't seem to work so it's possible that there may just be too much data or another problem is going on then!  But thank you for your suggestion!